# What's the origin of “Löcher in den Bauch fragen”?

Tags: etymology, idiom

I know that “Löcher in den Bauch fragen” means “to ask too many questions”, but I really can’t imagine the origin. Maybe because too many questions are annoying like a hole in the belly?

[image]

Comment: It sounds like a torturing method. Someone asks questions and if they don't get answers, they'll cutting your belly open.... I really hope this is not the true origin!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The usage of *Loch* to illustrate damage is known to be used in the context of letters or speech as early as in the 15th Century where the [Grimms](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GL06391#XGL06391) quote [Johann Geiler von Keisersberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Geiler_von_Kaisersberg):

> es sei kein Brief so gut, sie wölen ein **Loch** darein reden.

*[Bauch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GB01147#XGB01147)* in this context refers to the part of a body different to extremities or head. So "asking holes in a body" means to cause damage by asking too many questions. This also is used in the related idiom

> Jemand mit Fragen **löchern**

where the verb *[löchern](http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=l%C3%B6chern&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on)* in modern colloquial German is about to lose its meaning of *making holes* and mostly is used for pestering somebody with question.

> Dass Wieprecht bei den Konzerten im Kühlhaus am Gleisdreieck die Musiker mit seinen Laien-Fragen **löchert**, gefällt vielen im Publikum ganz besonders.<sup>[Der Tagesspiegel 25.04.2016](http://www.tagesspiegel.de/kultur/klassikerlebnis-durchs-kameraauge-als-kolibri-durch-den-saal-schweben/13494216.html)</sup>

Comment: Wie beantwortet das die Frage nach der Herkunft?

Comment: @npst, Herkunft unsicher, nachweisbar erst ab 15 Jh. Ist halt so.

Answer (score -2):

The Proto-Germanic root *luk(k)ōn- "to carress, lure, entice", "itterative verb of ambiguous origin" (cf. Kroonen 2013) has to be related to the verbal phrase, *jemanden mit Fragen Löchern*, cp. Old High German *lokkōn, lohhōn*, ie. *locken*.

Kroonen submits that "to caress" was ''clearly'' the allure of this semanteme and offers Lithuanian *lù(n)ginti* in support of the hypothesis. A more precise explanation is left up to the readers imagination.

Given the ididom "ein Loch in den Bauch fragen", the verbal phrase may be secondary because the Umlaut is otherwise difficult to explain. Reducing the noun to the suggestive sense it could easily refer to a sensation of desire and anxiety, which is naturally related to the stomach (*Gefühl, Schmetterlinge, Kribbeln im Bauch*; *unwohles Gefühl in der Magengegend*; *dir ist wohl eine Laus über die Leber gelaufen*, and similar).

---

1. Andere Theorien stellen für das Lithauische auf Vergleich mit *lügen* ab (Falk/Thorp apud Kroonen), so noch das Altlitauische Etymologische Wörterbuch, s.v. *luginti* "heucheln", "Wenn heth. [hethitisch] **haluka-* sc. ‘Nachricht, Botschaft’ hierher gehört, ..." ([ALEW](https://alew.hu-berlin.de/dict/1399)).

   Ansonsten wurde *locken* zumindest schonmal mit *Loch* verglichen ([DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/locken)) während man *lügen* als etymologisch unsicher betrachtet ([DWDS](https://dwds.de/wb/etymwb/l%C3%BCgen). Das liegt vermutlich an der Natur der Sache, vgl. z.B. *jmd. beleiern* (TODO: schon Althochdeutsch" täuschen", scheinbar nicht von *Leier* "lyre"), wobei allerlei Querschläger nicht auszuschließen sind (bspw. klingt *Laura* \lɔ.ʁ\ in schweizerischem Französisch der Erfahrung nach wie *Loch* [lɔχ]).

Vergleichbar auch *jmd. ein' Knopf an die Backe labern*. Wegen der Assonanz *Backe*, *Bauch* ist von einem ähnlichen Thema auszugehen.

Metaphern zeichnen sich ja gerade dadurch aus, dass Sie *nicht* wörtlich zu verstehen sind. Die üblicher Weise oberflächlichen Darstellungen (s. oben) bleiben deswegen darauf beschränkt, *jemandem ein Ohr abzukauen*.

---

2. Wegen Jiddish *lign*" lügen", das zudem auch *liegen* wiedergibt, bin ich zuvor der Vermutung erlegen, dass *auflauern* bzw. *im verborgenen liegen* dafür der richtige Ansatz sei, sowie ich mich auf der Jagd auch schon derart erniedrigt hatte, was zumindest mit Tocharisch B "thief" belegt werden kann (cf. Adams 2014: *lyak*).

   Jedoch liegt der umgekerhte Ansatz nah, ein seines Ur-Standes gemäß unterlegener würd regelmäßig nicht für ernst genommen werden. Das ist Eichmaß für die Fragestellung, weil *am Boden winselnd um Gnade betteln* eine gängige Metapher ist, bzw. eine unbarmherzige Realität, die mit vielen Metaphern wiedergegeben wird. Noch wichtiger ist im Vergleich vielleicht das reflexive *flachlegen*.
3. Deswegen ist bemerkenswert, dass *fragen* sogar ganz gut neben den Ableitungen von *erfreuen* steht. Das wäre angeblich urindogermanisch **preḱ-* "to ask" mit bspw. Litauisch *pir̃šti* "to arrange a marriage" bzw. andererseits **preyH* “to love, to please” mit Ossetisch лимӕн (limæn), нимӕл (nimæl) "friend, lover".

S.a. verderbt *sich ein zweites Loch in den Arsch freuen* (Low Saxon seems to know *Orsch* as "mouth", perhaps as alternation of *Goschen, Gusche*, and "zweites" must be interpolation). Q.e.d.

---

PS: Some Yiddisch sources know *laschoren*, "fragen", *loschore<sup>n</sup>* "ausfragen, auskundschaften, […]", apparently Jenisch, Rotwelsch (see Klepsch, Westjiddisches Wörterbuch). So there seems to be a loophole.

Answer (score -3):

Worry causes the stomach to hurt, but the phrase comes probably more from the sounds. The way it's said (often to children) is, "Du fragst mir ja ein Loch in den Bauch!" which in my part of Germany, sounds like, "lauwkinden Bauwk."

Comment: Wie beantwortet das die Frage nach der Herkunft? Für mich liest sich das wie ein Zirkelschluss: das kommt daher, weil man es so ausspricht. Hä?