# Wie entstand "Löcher in die Luft starren"

Tags: etymology, evolution

> 1. [umgangssprachlich] ⟨jmd. starrt Löcher in die Luft⟩ nicht zu tun haben, sich langweilen; nichts tun und dabei die Gedanken schweifen lassen. ● [spezieller] vor sich hin starren, nicht ansprechbar sein.

> 2. freie Zeit genießen, nichts tun und sich dabei entspannen.

> [*„Löcher in die Luft starren“, bereitgestellt durch das Digitale Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache, https://www.dwds.de/wb/L%C3%B6cher%20in%20die%20Luft%20starren, abgerufen am 24.02.2023.*]

Is it the same "usage of Loch to illustrate damage" (@tofro, [What's the origin of “Löcher in den Bauch fragen”?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/29456/whats-the-origin-of-l%c3%b6cher-in-den-bauch-fragen)) as is believed to be the result of *bohrende Fragen* or is this a rather boring question?

I find it difficult to explain as some sort of hurtful looks because it would more often be said of a stupified look, either in speechless awe or out of thumb twiddling boredom.

Was chin-dropping awe perhaps an initial component of this phrase? And how does *starry-eyed* star gazing relate to *starren* anyway?

Answer (score 1):

"Löcher in die Luft starren" refers to that absentminded stare at nothing in particular that we all have from time to time. In some situations it [helps us to concentrate](https://www.spektrum.de/frage/warum-starren-wir-beim-nachdenken-loecher-in-die-luft/852121) (short German article).

It's an old idea that looking at something is somehow affecting the thing being stared at (see for example "the evil eye", "his eyes are burning holes through me" and so forth). In antiquity there was the idea of "visual rays" that go from the eye to the viewed object, postulated for example by Euclid.

So it's not far fetched to think that when we stare absendmindedly at nothing in particular, at "thin air", our eyes are staring holes into the air.

Comment: "Not far fetched" is valid for your chosen interpretation, with which I have to agree, but it is too bizarre and very far fetched to suppose I would believe the conclusion. The Greek premise is literally far fetched. The evil eye is something so entirely different it doesn't bare mention (let's *face it*, looks and looking or Gesicht, Ansicht and Sicht are quite similar but  not that easily confused in practice).

Comment: *Wie Plutarchs Theorie lässt sich gemäß Haage eine solche Aussendung von Pneuma auf humoralpathologische Ansichten der Antike und des Mittelalters, welche ihre Ursprünge auch in der Emanationstheorie Platons haben, mit dem Konzept des „bösen Blicks“ in Einklang bringen, dessen Gegensatz **der ebenfalls vom Gehirn ausgehend gedachte „liebende Blick“** als Ursache (fascinatio) der Liebe zwischen Mann und Frau darstellt." (WP: Böser Blick) Micht deucht in der Tat, du erzähltest hier nur halbe Halbwahrheiten.

Comment: @vectory Ich habe eigentlich nur Beispiele für die seinerzeit verbreitete Vorstellung aufgezählt, beim Vorgang des Sehens würde etwas vom Auge ausgehen und sich auf das, was angesehen wird, auswirken. Zum Beispiel, indem man "Löcher in etwas starrt", in diesem Fall eben in die Luft.

Comment: 1. "Löcher in etwas starren" ist frei erfunden. "Löcher in die Luft starren" als Beispiel dafür heranzuziehen, um damit zu belegen, dass es das gibt, es allgemein gültig sei und dass "Löcher in die Luft starren" quasi sekundär daraus folgen würde ist ein unzulässig zirkuläres Argument. Du willst mich wohl verhohnepipeln.

Comment: 2. Auch die andern Beispiele geben das nicht ohne weiteres her. Medusas Blick versteinert, aber brennt nicht. "eyes are burning holes through me" entspricht vermutlich a) *burning desire* b) *glare*, bzw. *glühen* c) zu viel Chlor im Schwimmbad. *Hör auf Löcher in die Luft zu starren* müsste deiner etwaigen Antwort nach aber bedeuten, lass die Luft in Ruhe, guck da nicht so hin, sonst geht die Luft kaputt, die hat dir nichts getan. Das entspricht nicht einmal deiner eigenen Prämisse.

Comment: Das macht insbesondere keinen Sinn, weil Luft als Stoff,  den man betrachen könnte, sicher nicht Teil der besagten Vorstellungswelt ist.

Comment: @vectory Du hattest Deine Frage ursprünglich auf Englisch gestellt, und dort ist "to stare holes into somebody" oder ähnliche Wendungen durchaus verbreitet. Und wie gesagt, mir ging es rein darum die früher verbreitete Idee zu illustrieren, dass das Anschauen von etwas einen Effekt auf das Angeschaute habe. Es ist natürlich kein einzelner, direkter Schritt von "to stare holes into somebody" zu "Löcher in die Luft starren". Ich habe den Eindruck, Du interpretierst hier viel, viel zu viel in die Details.

Comment: Welche Details und Illustration? Besonders detailiert ist die Antwort ja nicht. Das "in die Luft starren" deutet insbesondere mit englisch *starry eyed* auf eine ältere Bedeutung von [Luft](https://dwds.de/wb/etymwb/Luft) während *in die Luft* im allgemeinen keine Sache bezeichnet. Hanns Guck-in-die-Luft begegnet sogar literatur kritisch ("Lieutenant Hans Guck in die Luft: Der Leutnant guckt nach den Fenstern, ob dort Mädchen herausschauen und stolpert dabei.", WP: Struwwelpeter § Militär-Struwwelpeter). M.m.n. ist "löcher" *offensichtlich* adverbiales Partizip und kein attributives Substantiv